# Shiny: Action button is not working after clicking enter

Tags: r, shiny

Action button in shiny is not working after clicking enter. Is there any way that I can get it working? 
Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to bind this manually. Try implementing the following, and replace `InputId` with the InputId for your actionButton.

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#InputId').click();
  }
});
```